# :blank selector not working on checkbox jQuery Validate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, checkbox

Hi I have currently have 2 fields and either 1 or the other need to be checked, these were initially using 2 text type inputs, now 1 of them needs to change from a text input to a checkbox.

Logic: IF the textbox has a value, checkbox is not required, 
IF checkbox is ticked, textbox is not required.

I was initially using the `:blank` selector to determine the validation and it was working, changed it to a checkbox and it broke, is there a different rule for checkbox's that I am missing from the validate() docs?

I am using the following versions:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
        //text 1
        'textbox': {
            required: "#certificate:blank",
            minlength: 8
        },

        //checkbox 1
        certificate: {
            required: "#textbox:blank"
        },
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="9" class=" form-textbox" id="textbox" name="textbox">
<input type="checkbox" class=" form-checkbox" id="certificate" name="certificate">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your code from

```
certificate: {
    required: "#textbox:blank"
},
```

to

```
// for checked
certificate: {
    required: "#textbox:checked"
},

// for unchecked
certificate: {
    required: function(element) {
        return !$("#textbox").is(":checked")
    }
},
```

For reference - http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/#example:-makes-details-required-only-if-#other-is-checked

Comment: Sorry not sure if I got my logic wrong but I would like it to be required if it is not checked.

Comment: legend, so you can return a object of either true or false, this is good to know. Thank you